# UnityEngine.CharacterInfo.width (etc) warnings

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

In this code fragment ...

```
charInfo.width = (int)ToFloat(charNode, "xadvance");
charInfo.flipped = false;
charInfo.uv = .. a Rect
```

I get these warnings...

> Assets/BitmapFontImporter.cs(54,42): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.CharacterInfo.width' is obsolete:` CharacterInfo.width is deprecated. Use advance instead.'
>
> Assets/BitmapFontImporter.cs(55,42): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.CharacterInfo.flipped' is obsolete:` CharacterInfo.flipped is deprecated. Use uvBottomLeft, uvBottomRight, uvTopRight or uvTopLeft instead, which will be correct regardless of orientation.'
>
> Assets/BitmapFontImporter.cs(63,42): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.CharacterInfo.uv' is obsolete:` CharacterInfo.uv is deprecated. Use uvBottomLeft, uvBottomRight, uvTopRight or uvTopLeft instead.'
>
> Assets/BitmapFontImporter.cs(73,42): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.CharacterInfo.vert' is obsolete:` CharacterInfo.vert is deprecated. Use minX, maxX, minY, maxY instead.'

BTW this is from the outstanding script: `BitmapFontImporter`  which is used widely.

**Note 3/2016** BitmapFontImporter on git has now been updated per d4Rk's perfect fix below!!  Is here: https://github.com/BenoitFreslon/BitmapFontImporter

Comment: Can't you ignore it?  It's just a warning and not in your code.  Anyway here's the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterInfo.html).

Comment: Haha, I wasn't kidding - it happens alot with code from the asset store and I don't normally worry about it and wait for the author to fix it.  I'm obviously OCD about my own code, however.

Comment: Actually you really can ship projects with warnings.. Maybe you should just differentiate between the warnings.. "deprecated" just means, it may be gone in the future.. there are really worse warnings.. But ok, for sure its better to have less or no warnings at all.

Comment: Somehow the script even isn't working properly for me, without making any modifications to it -.-

Comment: I'm using unity on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the script wasn't working for me at all in Unity 5.3.1, I got rid of all those Warnings (by using the recommended "new" methods)..

After a quick test in the Editor it seems to be working quite well again.

[image]
*Note: I used the free version of `Glyph Designer`, that's the reason for the watermark on the chars.. But you can see the chars are positioned and sized correctly.*

### Here's the diff:

```
-   XmlNode kernings = xml.GetElementsByTagName("kernings")[0];

-   charInfo.width = (int)ToFloat (charNode, "xadvance");
-   charInfo.flipped = false;
+   charInfo.advance = (int)ToFloat (charNode, "xadvance");

-   charInfo.uv = r;
+   charInfo.uvBottomLeft = new Vector2(r.xMin, r.yMin);
+   charInfo.uvBottomRight = new Vector2(r.xMax, r.yMin);
+   charInfo.uvTopLeft = new Vector2(r.xMin, r.yMax);
+   charInfo.uvTopRight = new Vector2(r.xMax, r.yMax);

-   charInfo.vert = r;
+   charInfo.minX = (int)r.xMin;
+   charInfo.maxX = (int)r.xMax;
+   charInfo.minY = (int)r.yMax;
+   charInfo.maxY = (int)r.yMin;
```

**See also:**
https://github.com/BenoitFreslon/BitmapFontImporter/pull/2/commits

Comment: So, warnings are gone? Works as expected? :-)

Comment: hey @d4Rk ! yes, perfect.  I clicked over the bounty and THANKS!  for future readers the d4Rk fix is now in the version on github.

Comment: check out @d4Rk  my new BOUNTY CHALLENGE  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540406/get-correct-position-of-letters-using-cachedtextgenerator-bounty