# Get correct position of letters using cachedTextGenerator

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

Consider a `Text` with many paragraphs of text. It's easy to **find where a certain character is**, using [UICharInfo](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UICharInfo.html).

Example, find all newlines...

```
TextGenerator tg = text.cachedTextGenerator;
int kText = tg.characterCount;
for (int i=0; i < kText; ++i)
  {
  if ( text.text[i] == '\n' )
    Debug.Log("found a newline at " + tg.verts[i * 4].position.y);
  }
```

This gives the correct ratios ***but they are all out by some scaling factor***.

It seems to depend on many things (screen shape, pixels, settings and more).

Naturally this is in a `Canvas` using scale-with-screen-size.

**How do you get the actual offset of a character - to use in a scroll view to scroll to that point**?

Comment: will be adding ***enormous bounty .. maybe more than 12 points*** for this as soon as the bounty period is open.  get in now to profit

Comment: _"maybe more than 12 points"_ - lol :)

Comment: HEH ...  come and get it, programmers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a combination of text.pixelsPerUnit and what they call a rounding offset. The code they use is open source and can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0155c39e05ca5d7dcc97d9974256ef83bc122586/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Text.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default). The relevant lines you are looking for are in the function

```
protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper toFill)
```

All the functions they use to calculate them are public and should be easy enough to duplicate on your side

Comment: an incredible tip Colton. I will look in to it.

Comment: Colton, you deservedly win the bounty -- thanks!  Another SEC win  :)  I think I'll start another bounty question to try to get "someone to write code for this" heh