# Rect Transform position of an individual letter ( char ) in Unity UI

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, char, substring, transform

Is it possible to get the position of an individual char in a string in Unity?

So if I had a block of text like: **"I want a button here @"**

I could place an object ( like a button! ) where the @ symbol is.

many thanks...

Comment: Hi Mark!  good one, you do this using `TextGenerator`.  And, I have a question about it, ***WITH A BOUNTY***, right here! http://stackoverflow.com/a/35557536/294884   Let's hope someone answers

Comment: cheers Joe, I'll check it out.